# "Is one of you" vs "Are one of you"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, be

> *Is* one of you near my office?
> *Are* one of you near my office?

ChatGPT says that they are both grammatically correct which means people use both (i.e., there exits mass confusion). The subject is "one" which would imply the first but that option still sounds weird.

I thought it was time to move from AI to RI - that's where you come in!

Comment: "you" complicates the situation, as we say "You are..." .  I don't know of any speakers who would say this:  "I'm looking for some pencils. *Are one of them* in the drawer?"

Comment: The partitive sentence "Is one of you near my office?" means "**Is** one member of some group x near my office?"

Comment: “Is one of you near my office?”; “Are some of you near my office?” ChatGPT gets answers correct some of the time, but hallucinates much too often.

Comment: The second is incorrect as it implies "Are any of you near my office." In this case, the subject is everyone a part of the target group ("any of you"), where in the former sentence, the subject is directed to the person(s) who satisfy (if any) the interrogation.

Comment: Thanks all for confirming.  @PeterShor: Interesting reference to hallucinations.  I "knew" the right answer and was yet tempted to use the wrong.  Did we replicate that part of our nature in the AI?